# Zoom limit in orthographicTrackballControls

Tags: three.js

Current version of THREE.js supports for limiting zoom(in and out) in Trackball controls.

```
var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera,renderer.domElement);
controls.minDistance = 20;
controls.maxDistance = 80;
```

But I don't find any property in orthographicTrackballControls for limiting zoom. Is there a solution?